# The method 'data' was called on null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I made this function to get document(post)'s userId but docu always becomes null.
Is there any ideas to solve this problem?
(I use flutter and cloud firestore)

```
Future<String> getUserId(String text) async{
var docu;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('post')
    .where('content', isEqualTo: '$text')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((snapshot){
   snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    docu = document;
    print('docUserId : ${document.data()['userId']}'); // this works well
  });
});
return docu.data()['userId']; }
```

[image]

Also I tried return only document userId with String like this

```
Future<String> getUserId(String text) async{
String docUserId;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('post')
    .where('content', isEqualTo: '$text')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((snapshot){
   snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    docUserId = document.data()['userId'];
    print('docUserId : ${docUserId}'); // this works well
  });
});
return docUserId; }
```

Although print('docUserId : ${docUserId}'); this command works well, the final return value is always null.
I can't find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of 3 importand points here:

1. You don't need to have a realtime listener if you just want to get the data once
2. You can't await a listener. Your function will always end before you get the data.
3. Check if a document exists before you use it

Could you pls try it with this code:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<String> getUserId(String text) async {
  String userUid = '';
  QuerySnapshot docSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('post')
      .where('content', isEqualTo: '$text')
      .get();

  docSnap.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    if (document.exists) {
      userUid = document.data()['userId'];
      print('docUserId : ${document.data()['userId']}');
    }
  });

  return userUid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.data()

change this to

docu = document;

print('docUserId : ${docu['userId']}');

Comment: Then check the firebase data .the snapshot is exists or not